# Appcelerator simple textfield not showing

Tags: android, textfield, titanium, appcelerator

Greetings,

I'm trying to simply display a blank textfield (I know), but it's not working?

I must be making some simple error.

Here is my app.js:

```
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#FFF');

var win1=Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Login',
    backgroundColor:'#FFF'
});

var uname = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    color:'#336699',
    height:35,
    top:50,
    width:250,
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});

win1.add(uname);
```

Am I missing something? The above should work, right?

I'm using Android emulator on Ubuntu x86_64

When I use tabs the uname and label appear ok:

```
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();

var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Tab 1',
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
});
var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
    icon:'KS_nav_views.png',
    title:'Tab 1',
    window:win1
});

var uname=Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    color:'#336699',
    height:35,
    top:50,
    width:250,
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED
});
var label1=Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    color:'#999',
    text:'hello',
    font:{fontSize:20,fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},
    textAlign:'center',
    width:'auto'
});

win1.add(uname);
win1.add(label1);

tabGroup.addTab(tab1);
tabGroup.open();
```

But how do I get rid of the tabs???

I've tried several versions of Android (1.6 API and 2.2 API)

Many thanks in advance,

Update: the solution is:
Add the following line:
win1.open({fullscreen:true});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this on the end of you app.js

```
win1.open({fullscreen:true});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It works! Thank you so, so much. I just hope I don't encounter any more of these seemingly impassable crevasses on my Appcelerator travels.

Comment: @Eamorr i am working with Appcelerator and these questions help me get better at it, feel free to ask away also check out some stuff on my blog

Comment: It's really amazing being able to talk to people working at the heart of a project from the other side of the world. May I suggest having a selection of, say ten, really simple examples starting with showing just some text and finishing with something like two textboxes and a button with XMLHttpWebRequest. The kitchen sink is great, but it's very daunting at first! Thanks again,